# Jetty HttpClient proxy authentication configuration (NTLM)

Tags: java, proxy, jetty, ntlm-authentication, jetty-httpclient

We built a Java client application connecting to an API behind a proxy that demands NTLM authentication. The application uses a Jetty HttpClient.

Unfortunately the authentication fails with a 407

```
Response headers HttpResponse[HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required]@3577846e
Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
```

We tried to authenticate using the SPNEGOAuthentication-class

```
AuthenticationStore authStore = httpClient.getAuthenticationStore();
SPNEGOAuthentication auth = new SPNEGOAuthentication(proxyUrl);
auth.setUserName(user);
auth.setUserPassword(password);
authStore.addAuthentication(auth);

ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = httpClient.getProxyConfiguration();

HttpProxy proxy = new HttpProxy(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort());
proxyConfig.getProxies().add(proxy);
```

But without success (407). We also tried overwriting the DefaultAuthenticator.

Any hints what we probably did wrong or other suggestions?

Regards and thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Is your `user` variable following the format of `<user>@<realm>` ?

Comment: Actually we just used <user>. Is a realm required in NTLM authentication?

Comment: That I cannot answer, the realm requirement is site specific.   Most sites I've personally come across require it.  But yours might be different.